# C++ Serial Communications - The way to go on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

After spending some hours on Internet I got frustrated about serial communications way to go using C++ running on Linux environments.

It seens there is a lot of options and even some confusion on how to go for it, with a lot of pasted code everywhere with very few explanations about those flags controlling communications behaviour. Things I´ve found includes:

`termios.h`: A library that may be obsolete and seens to have com "C" old style coding principle. I could not find a good documentation on that.

`boost::serial_port`: The common boost library - a good way to go for those who love it, and a discarded path for those who wants to be "close" to the language and OS as possible (as myself).

`Github libraries`: There are some good libraries....

As a serial port works in fact with a stream of bytes I can assume I can built it  much like `std::cout` and `std::cin`, a `file` or a `stringstream`.

If that is the fact, it should be reasonably straightfoward to build serial communications code: a simple `open/close/read/write` would do the job, but  then comes port setting (baud rate, parity, etc...), cannonical vs non-cannonical implementation, timeouts, etc...

No that I don´t understand how serial communication works, but I need some advice on where to start from on Linux... I really don´t want to use `boost` neither "C" style coding inside C++.

So I ask for suggestions for up-to-dated path to construct my serial communications classes, where I can build a clear C++ code without loosing the communication handling mechanisms needed on a robust implementation.

Modern and up-to-dated docs, examples and opinions are very welcomed...

BTW: I´m using Ubuntu as the OS.

Comment: How close to the hardware do you want or need?  Do you want to use an existing driver or write one?

Comment: Are you supporting USB or RS232?

Comment: It's difficult to decide if this question is too broad, or off-topic because you're asking for library recommendations. I recommend you take a look at [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Although, I personally am interested in the answers.

Comment: You couldn't find any good documentation on termios? Where did you look?! That interface has been around for over 25 years; there's *tons* of documentation all over the Internet. (Heck, even Wikipedia has a decent overview…)

Comment: Thomas, serial is serial, I don´t think USB or RS232 makes a difference except for UART deep control...